# Bootstrap 4 collapse doesn't work with bootstrap from nuget

Tags: bootstrap-4

Using asp.net web forms to create my bootstrap page.
When I use this scrpts:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

everything works fine.
but when I get bootstrap 4.5.2 from nuget and add like this:

```
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

bootstrap classes work but collapse doesn't work anymore.
I checked the version of Jquery: 3.5.1. and popper it is 1.16.0, but still doesn't work.
Is there any solution?